# Xcode cant click button after moving button frame

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I created a button in the Interface Builder with a tag 10

In code

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x,btn.frame.origin.y+changeInPos, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height);
```

changeInPos could be any number lets say its 100. So my button moves down 100 but it no longer works in its new position nor does it work if I click where it used to be.

Have I done something wrong after moving the button? If its useful to know I have turned off use autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation is that the button moves out of the frame of its containing view. In this case, it will not receive touches.